# Return a word in an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of various words in which I want to check the first word found in this string from the array of words.

```
const arrayOfWord=['@Robot','@Human','@Animal','@Hero']
const body = 'This is a try to found the @Human & the @Animal'

arrayOfWord.some(arrayOfWord=> body.includes(arrayOfWord)) // This will return true 
// i want to get the value @Human as it's the first word in the string that exists in the array
```

I want to get `value = '@Human'`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: First based on array order or string order?

Comment: Will the word(s) always start with `@`?

Comment: @charlietfl String order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to split *body* into array and then filter out all words that aren't in *arrayOfWord*. After such transformation you can pick up first element.

```
body.split(" ").filter(word => arrayOfWord.includes(word))[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [**.find()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of `.some()`

The `.find()` method returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

```js
const arrayOfWord=['@Robot','@Human','@Animal','@Hero']
const body = 'This is a try to found the @Human & the @Animal'

const res = arrayOfWord.find(arrayOfWord => body.includes(arrayOfWord))
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Note order of array happens to match order in string for this example. May not always be the case. Carification is needed as to what determines "first"

Comment: Thank you that's it

Comment: @Lisa123456 this answer is incorrect. Test with const arrayOfWord=['@Robot','@Animal','@Human','@Hero'] it will yield Animal, even though it's behind Human in the body string.

Comment: @charlietfl "I want to check the first word found in this string from the array of words." The first word found in this string from the array of words - I think - means that we want to find the first occurrence of any words in the array. Unless the array is a collection of words with descending priority, which is not indicated, the result of the algorithm should be the same for this string with any permutation of the array items.

Answer (score 0):

As your example shows there could be multiple words occuring in the text and we are searching for the earliest. Please take a look at the code below:

```
const arrayOfWord=['@Robot','@Human','@Animal','@Hero']
const body = 'This is a try to found the @Human & the @Animal'

var output = undefined;
arrayOfWord.filter((arrayOfWord)=> {
    let retVal = ((body.indexOf(arrayOfWord) >= 0) ? body.indexOf(arrayOfWord) : false);
    if (retVal !== false) {
        if ((!output) || (output.index > retVal)) output = {index : retVal, word: arrayOfWord};
    }
    return retVal !== false;
})
console.log(output ? output.word : undefined);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lisa!
Maybe it can help you...

```
const arrayOfWord=['@Robot','@Human','@Animal','@Hero']
const body = 'This is a try to found the @Human & the @Animal'

// Get the @Human index
indexOfHuman = arrayOfWord.indexOf('@Human')

//This line will get the value of @Human
valueOfHuman = arrayOfWord[indexOfHuman]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map your array of words to an array of indexes of where each word appears in the string. Then you can use `.reduce()` to find the minimum value number in the array which are not `-1`.

See example below:

```js
const arrayOfWord = ['@Robot','@Human','@Animal','@Hero'];
const body = 'This is a try to found the @Human & the @Animal';

const arrayOfIdx = arrayOfWord.map(wrd => body.indexOf(wrd))
const minItemIdx = arrayOfIdx.reduce((min, idx, i) => 
  idx === -1 || (arrayOfIdx[min] !== -1 && arrayOfIdx[min] < idx) ? min : i, 0);

const res = arrayOfWord[minItemIdx];
console.log(res);
```